# Reading specific lines from a file and writing to another file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file containing 1000 lines. First 15 lines will be header information.

I am trying to do the below :-

1) Read the file
2)Get the number of lines with header information. It will return 15
3)write lines 1-15 to a text file.

I am able to do 1 and 2 correctly, but not the 3rd step. Any inputs please?

Below is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy;
import os; 
import math;
import cPickle; import time
from numpy import arange, sign
import copy
import re 
import sys  
import string
import mmap
head_lines = 0;
count=1
fide = open("text1.txt","r");
while (count==1):  #We skip header
   head_lines = head_lines+1;
   line = fide.readline();
   if 'END OF HEADER' in line:
    print 'End of the Header reached'
    break
print "hello world"
print head_lines
nlines = head_lines;
key=1;
while (key < nlines):
 file1 = open("Header.txt","w")
 lines = fide.readline()
 file1.write(lines)
 key = key+1;
print "done"
```

Comment: what are your current results?

Comment: Its printing the 16th line. The line after header

Comment: I know you didn't ask for this, but you should look into [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and consider writing your code accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("input.txt") as f1:
   with open("output.txt","w") as f2:
        for _ in range(15):
            f2.write(f1.readline())
```

is that what you are asking for?

(in python2.7 I think you can do `with open('f1') as f1,open('f2','w') as f2: ...`)

Comment: Thank you Joran. It helped me

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

1. What ever you are writing in the file `header.txt` you'll be overwriting it every time you loop on the second `while` because you are re-opening the file which will put the file pointer to its origin i.e. the start of the file.
2. The second issue is similar but on the other file `fide`. You open it putting the file pointer to the start of the file and read one line until the end of the headers. And in the second `while` loop you keep reading lines from the same file pointer `fide` so you're reading the next `nlines`.

You could store the header's lines in a list and then write those strings in the output file.